# Unreadable Characters in Apache HttpClient

Tags: java, http

I'm trying to login to a webpage, but even before that, I'm loading the page using HttpGet, and this is one the lines that's being returned,
`ÓA;`
That's all I could put, won't let me paste any other characters. But they are all like that, like I'm somehow getting the wrong encoding? Here is the code I am using to GET

```
      HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
      if(headers == null) {
          headers = getDefaultHeaders();
      }
      for(String s : headers.keySet()) {
          httpget.addHeader(s, headers.get(s));
      }
        HttpResponse response = getClient().execute(httpget);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        System.out.println("Status Line: " + response.getStatusLine());
        if (entity != null) {
            InputStream input = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
            String ln = "";
            while((ln = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("During Get - " + ln);
            }
        }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help.

If you need any more information like headers, just ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line is possibly the cause of your problems:

```
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
```

You are creating a reader using the default characterset of your platform, and completely ignoring any character set that may be specified in the HTTP response headers.

---

If you are getting the same problem when reading the content the correct way, then it is possible that the server is at fault for not setting the response header correctly.

Comment: Thanks for this, will the method that Mauricio showed me automatically read it correctly?

Comment: Judging from the source code, it should do.  Though you need to correct the obvious mistake.

Comment: Sorry I guess I just don't see, what mistake do you mean?

Comment: You know ... the one that stops it compiling :-)

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about, It's compiling for me :O

Comment: Really?  EntityUtils.EntityUtils?

Comment: O that, I got rid of that before I compiled, and by the way, that wasn't my Code :)

Answer (score 1):

DO the entity reading like this:

```
String content = org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString( entity );
System.out.println(content);
```

This is going to read it all for you so you can check what's being really returned.

Comment: Thanks this makes it easier, but unfortunately, doesn't fix the problem :( Still showing the same characters

Comment: Then these are the only characters that come from your response. Try to make exactly the same call using CURL to make sure the result is what you really think it is.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you didn't accidentally go to port 443 with a simple HTTP connection. Because in that case you will get back the SSL handshake instead of an HTTP response.